# Select pixels in an array using a structuring element in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I'm searching a way to select "pixels" in an array using a structuring element:
Imagine we have that array a, and that structuring element s,

```
a=np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
         [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
         [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
         [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
         [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
         [35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41],
         [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48]])
s=np.array([[0,1,0],
         [1,1,1],
         [0,1,0]])
```

I'm then searching for a function that will act like

```
f(a, position=(3,3), structure=s) = [17,23,24,25,31]
```

It looks like scipy.ndimage morphology functions can do that internally. A workaround would be to create a np.zeros array with the same shape as a, put a 1 at a position of interest and the dilate it, but that would be very resource consuming - especially since my arrays are not 7 * 7.

Comment: You can extract only the submatrix of interest using linear indexing, and then apply the boolean indexing. So something like `a[2:5,2:5][s != 0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer using `view_as_windows` (which uses numpy strides under the hood):

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows
def f(a, position, structure):
  return view_as_windows(a,structure.shape)[tuple(np.array(position)-1)][structure.astype(bool)]
```

output:

```
f(a, position=(3,3), structure=s)
#[17 23 24 25 31]
```

if you feed the `position` as numpy array instead of tuple and `structure` as boolean array instead of int, the answer will even be shorter since you will not need conversions:

```
def f(a, position, structure):
      return view_as_windows(a,structure.shape)[tuple(position-1)][structure]
```